# Best way to hide inline CSS and JavaScript from downlevel browsers

Tags: javascript, css, comments

What is the best way to hide inline Javascript and CSS from downlevel browsers?  ... I see a few variations on a common theme.  Are they all correct, or is one approach better than the other?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
    // Forces the treeview to adjust to the new size of its container
    function resizeTree(DomElementId, NewPaneHeight, NewPaneWidth) {
        //do stuff
    }

  //-->
</script>
```

vs

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    /* Javascript code here */
//]]>
</script>
```

vs

```
  <style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/     CSS stuff here       /*]]>*/    </style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example is the ancient pre-HTML 3.2 method to [hide contents](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#idx-user_agent) of the `script` element to browsers that didn't recognize them. You don't have to use it anymore. Every current browser (of which IE 6 is the oldest) recognizes these elements and knows that it shouldn't bluntly show their contents. By the way, the `language` attribute of the `script` element has been [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1) long ago, too.

Your second and third examples contain [CDATA markers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA), embedded within comments appropriate for the script or style language used. Use those when you embed inline scripts or stylesheets in XHTML documents (and only then). Without those markers a parser would think that ampersands and less-than signs represent special entities or the beginning of tags, respectively. To quote [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA):

> Since it is useful to be able to use
>   less-than signs (<) and ampersands (&)
>   in web page scripts, and to a lesser
>   extent styles, without having to
>   remember to escape them, it is common
>   to use CDATA markers around the text
>   of inline `<script>` and `<style>`
>   elements in XHTML documents. But so that
>   the document can also be parsed by
>   HTML parsers, which do not recognise
>   the CDATA markers, the CDATA markers
>   are usually commented-out

This is done the way you show in your second and third examples. The former shows a Javascript example, the latter a CSS snippet.

Also see [Comments and CDATA: The mysterious history of script and style in HTML](http://dorward.me.uk/www/comments-cdata/).

Comment: Does any of this change when dealing with CSS embedded within an email message?  e.g. a blackberry client, or other device

Comment: @Maker – I really doubt it, as we're still dealing with XHTML. But, if possible, I would send an HTML email as HTML (with HTML 5 Doctype) and not as XHTML, thereby circumventing this whole issue (or rather, send email as plain text, but that's more a personal preference).